# Best Grinder for DeLonghi Dedica EC685

Tags: grinder

What is the best grinder to use with a DeLonghi Dedica EC685? I’m aware that the portafilter uses pressurized baskets, so tamping and grind size is not as critical as on more professional espresso machines. But as a consumer machine that allows you the flexibility of using your own coffee grounds, a decent grinder that executes a grind size this Dedica EC685 can use would be ideal.

What grinder (whether burr/blade) is a good grinder that allows the optimum grind size for the pressurized baskets on the Dedica EC685, as well as offering you enough range to grind coarser for pour overs, drips & french presses?

Would you recommend something like the KRUPS GVX2 (my current grinder) with only 16-18 grind settings? [incidentally this functions, and offers almost identical performance to the DeLonghi KG 79]

Or would your recommend a Baratza Encore or Virtuoso, with 40 grind settings? Or something even higher pro model grinder?

For users of this Dedica EC685, what grinders are you using and are happy with? (Brands, models & types, please)

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd go with the baratza encore (or something similar). It will do just fine for a pressurised basket and it's great for filter too (if James Hoffman uses it for his filter it's good enough for you and me). Don't buy a blade grinder, I've made that mistake. You will taste a huge difference between the two, the blade grinder being bitter and yucky. It's all about particle distribution and a blade grinder does the worst possible job at that.

So, spend the money for a decent burr grinder and you won't only have better espresso; you can make delicious filter coffee too!

Comment: The Baratza Encore is probably good for pressurized baskets, but you should note that it won't work if they ever want to try non-pressurized. I have the Encore myself, but it doesn't do fine enough for espresso and if it wouldn't then it lacks the settings to properly fine tune it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Appreciate it. Pressurised baskets are the best inventions since sliced bread... I'm not saying they're the best option when pulling an espresso shot, but as a great invention they've dramatically made pulling decent shots from inferior grounds possible. As an insta-espresso, it serves as a great middle ground between a real espresso machine and a pod machine.

But has anyone here used the DeLonghi Dedica EC685 extensively to be able to confirm a good grinder to work alongside it?